# On firing click event, first fires the Radio Button selectedindexchanged event and then the click event.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, selectedindexchanged, onclientclick

On editing i am assigning the radio button check value, it is Checked proper to my radio button value, but when I click the update button,it fires radio button  **SelectedIndexChanged**
event first and then fires an update button click event(radio button autopostback property is true)

***(Here on edit button i assign value to control, for this i m using jquery which is done perfectly. When i click update button it fires radio button event first then it fires update click event. I have to avoid radio button SelectedIndexChanged event)***

For assigning I am using this code:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabLTA_tbVouchers_rbtType_0').attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: Turn off Autopostback for radio if you dont need it

Comment: It is not clear what you question is. Add some more code and details.

Comment: @RabNawaz That does not prevent the `SelectedIndexChanged` event from firing

Comment: @RabNawaz autopostback is used in my code i writen SelectedIndexChanged event on that